# Updating a Swift Struct and Accessing the New Value in Completion Block Returns Nil

Tags: ios, swift, struct, closures, mutability

I have an issue mutating a struct and then retrieving the new data in a completion block. Here is the code:

```
class APIRequestManager {

    func fetchCharacterExtendedData(completion: (json: [String: AnyObject], error: NSError?) -> Void) {

        // do some network stuff...
        let json = ["nickname": "Chris"]
        completion(json: json, error: nil)
    }
}

struct Character {

    let name: String?
    var extendedInfo: CharacterExtendedInfo?

    init(json: [String: AnyObject]) {

        name = json["name"] as? String
    }

    struct CharacterExtendedInfo {

        var nickname: String

        init(json: [String: AnyObject]) {

            nickname = json["nickname"] as! String
        }
    }
}

extension Character {

    mutating func fetchExtendedInfo(completion: () -> Void) {

        let requestManager = APIRequestManager() // Going one level deeper here seems to be the issue
        requestManager.fetchCharacterExtendedData() { json, error in

            self.extendedInfo = CharacterExtendedInfo(json: json)
            completion()
        }
    }
}

var character = Character(json: ["name": "Christopher"])
character.fetchExtendedInfo {
    print("Completed...")
    print("Nickname: \(character.extendedInfo?.nickname)") // The value's missing!
}

print("Nickname: \(character.extendedInfo?.nickname)") // Correctly prints "Chris"
```

Can anybody explain why this is and how I can fix it so the extendedInfo variable is populated correctly within the completion closure?

Thanks

Comment: The code should work. Consider to watch the printed values in the console rather than those in the result column of the Playground. And pass the `json` parameter to the `CharacterExtendedInfo` initializer instead of the literal dictionary.

Comment: You might want to rename your `Character` struct, there's one already defined by swift and you may get conflicts: [Character](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_Character_Structure/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/struct/s:Vs9Character)

Comment: @vadian Thanks guys. You were quite right. However my code was a little more complex than what I first posted. I've updated the code now which does in fact feature this same problem with getting nil in the closure. Any more thoughts?